# QFlags python alternative

Tags: python

In PyQt4, what is the alternative for:

```
class TestClass
 {
 public:
     enum Option {
         OptionA = 0x0,  // 0x000000
         OptionB = 0x1,  // 0x000001
         OptionC = 0x2,  // 0x000010
         OptionD = 0x4,  // 0x000100
         OptionE = 0x8,  // 0x001000
         OptionE = 0x10 // 0x010000
         // ... some more options with value which is a power of two
     };
     Q_DECLARE_FLAGS(Options, Option)
 };

 Q_DECLARE_OPERATORS_FOR_FLAGS(TestClass::Options)
```

How do I convert this block to python?